# ASP.NET: How do I navigate to a page after clicking a checkbox?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, autopostback

I have some `checkboxes` and a `dropdownlist` when the value changes I want to refresh the page while passing the new value.  I tried using `autopostback`; however, the value is already in the url previously so when the postback occurs the value never changes.

Example:

`CurrentPage: page.aspx?tab=Home&checkbox=True`

Then I uncheck the checkbox so I want it to go to the following page...

`IntendedPage: page.aspx?tab=Home&checkbox=False`

But instead I the autopostback gives me this page...

`DestinationPage: page.aspx?tab=Home&checkbox=True`

Because, I handle the building of the url through a function on my page.  Perhaps I'm doing something wrong by this point.  If so I'd be happy to be corrected on my current setup.  What I think I need to know though is how to load a custom URL on the checkbox.checkchanged event.  I hope this made sense, if not let me know I'll try and clarify it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy to do through javascript.  First add `onclick="checkCheckBox(this);"` to your checkbox.

```
<script language = "javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function checkCheckBox(checkbox) {
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            window.location.href = '../page.aspx?tab=Home&checkbox=True';
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = '../page.aspx?tab=Home&checkbox=False';
        }
    }
</script>
```

This should do it pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this ( I have not tested, it was just an idea).

```
 protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        string url = "page.aspx?tab=Home&checkbox="+ CheckBox1.Checked.ToString();
        Response.Redirect ( url );
    }
```

And then on the page:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
```

**VB.NET Conversion**

```
Protected Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
       Dim url = "page.aspx?tab=Home&checkbox=" & CheckBox1.Checked.ToString()
       Response.Redirect(url)
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried your method with the VB.NET code I provided in the edit above. Everything compiles correctly, but the onCheckedChanged doesn't seem to take place... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is caused by the [viewstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx). The `checkbox` use it to persists its property, especially the `checked` property.

Actually, there is no out of the box link between a control and query string.

In your case, you will have two options, depending on your needs :

- in the `Checked` event, build the expected url, and [`redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309.aspx) the user to this page. The drawback is that you "loose" the viewstate and thus, the controls' state.
- instead of using postbacks, use client side script (jQuery is your friend) to hide/show parts of the page. If the url matters, use # in the urls because it does allow staying on the same page.